# MongoDB in Luigi

Tags: luigi

I was trying to build a pipeline with luigi. First by getting data from an API, transform and then save it to a mongo db. I'm still new to luigi, my question is how do I implement the output() function which specifies outputs to a mongo db. And how would I create the require() function for subsequent tasks?

The first one, I was trying to attempt the demo [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407936/mysql-targets-in-luigi-workflow), but it's using MySql instead of mongodb. So I tried

```
from luigi.contrib.mongodb import MongoTarget
from pymongo import MongoClient

def output(self):
    # connect to db
    connection = MongoClient(self.host, self.port)
    db_client = connection[self.db_name]
    collection_name = 'myCollection'

    return MongoTarget(db_client, '_id', collection_name)
```

but it gave me error like this:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MongoTarget with abstract methods exists
```

A quick search of the error seems like due to [pyMongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28201985/abstract-classes-and-pymongo-cant-instantiate-abstract-class), but that solution still doesn't fix it.

For the require part, I'm not sure how to approach it either, I would like to check on if the records existed alraedy so I don't duplicate them. But there is no unique index from my API data, so I guess I have to somehow scan over all the records to make sure there are no duplicates.

There isn't a lot of documentation or examples on using mongo with luigi, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used the mongodb package myself but it appears your first problem is due to a misuse of the MongoTarget interface.
If you look at the code in here:

https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/luigi/contrib/mongodb.py#L25

you see that you would need to pass an instance of the MongoClient (`connection` in your case instead of `db_client`). You are right though, there is hardly any documentation for non-core Luigi packages. I developed a habit of reading the codebase to understand how to use a given package when working with Luigi (which now turned into a habit with any library I use)

Having said that, I don't think the MongoTarget is an actual target; It doesn't implement the `exists` method. You should instead use the other Targets provided in the module, namely `MongoCellTarget`, `MongoRangeTarget`, `MongoCollectionTarget` etc
Read their docstring for further info on what they do!

Comment: You are right, I also found about that from the [issue](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/pull/2062) section on lugi's repo, haven't got chance to run it yet. Thanks for sharing. I see, then I will look into other targets method.

Comment: I tried with just putting in the mongoclient directly in the Target class, it still doesn't work. Same error.

Answer (score 2):

The Luigi code base [has a test](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/blob/master/test/contrib/mongo_test.py) for the `luigi.contrib.mongodb` package. The test uses `MongoCellTarget` and `MongoRangeTarget`. That test worked for me and was good enough to build upon.

The following snippet is derived from that test, and assumes an empty MongoDB instance running on `localhost`.

```
import pymongo
from luigi.contrib.mongodb import MongoRangeTarget

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 27017
INDEX = 'luigi_test'
COLLECTION = 'luigi_collection'

mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient(HOST, PORT)
collection = mongo_client[INDEX][COLLECTION]

# Add sample data
test_docs = [
    {'_id': 'person_1', 'age': 11, 'experience': 10, 'content': "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet. Consectetur adipiscing elit."},
    {'_id': 'person_2', 'age': 12, 'experience': 22, 'content': "Sed purus nisl. Faucibus in, erat eu. Rhoncus mattis velit."},
    {'_id': 'person_3', 'age': 13, 'content': "Nulla malesuada, fringilla lorem at pellentesque."},
    {'_id': 'person_4', 'age': 14, 'content': "Curabitur condimentum. Venenatis fringilla."}
]

collection.insert_many(test_docs)

## Test reading from MongoDB via MongoRangeTarget    
test_values = [
    ('age', [], {}),
    ('age', ['unknown_person'], {}),
    ('age', ['person_1', 'person_3'], {'person_1': 11, 'person_3': 13}),
    ('age', ['person_1', 'person_3', 'person_5'], {'person_1': 11, 'person_3': 13}),
    ('experience', ['person_1', 'person_3'], {'person_1': 10}),
    ('experience', ['person_1', 'person_3', 'person_5'], {'person_1': 10}),
]

for field, ids, result in test_values:
    target = MongoRangeTarget(mongo_client, INDEX, COLLECTION, ids, field)
    assertEqual(result, target.read())
```